# How to find rows that contain any string from a list and store the matched string as a new column?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a list called colors that looks like this:

```
colors = c("Red", "Yellow", "Blue")
```

Products dataframe looks like this, I want to add the column "NewColumn", Look for all values from the colors list in the "name" column and store it as a new column.

(Please see attached image)[image]

Comment: Is there a specific issue? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic]. Also, please share the data as text, not an image.

Comment: Please don't add data as images, they are not helpful. Read how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can `paste` `colors` into one string and use  `str_extract_all` to extract all the colors.

```
colors = c("Red", "Yellow", "Blue")
df$New_column <- sapply(stringr::str_extract_all(df$Name, 
                       paste0('\\b', colors, '\\b', collapse = '|')), toString)
df

#            Name Quantity New_column
#1 Red Blue Dress        1  Red, Blue
#2       Blue Bat        2       Blue
#3      Blue Coat        3       Blue
#4   Yellow Dress        4     Yellow
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Name = c("Red Blue Dress", "Blue Bat", "Blue Coat", 
"Yellow Dress"), Quantity = 1:4), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```